# Cross-referencing tables in appendix

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, appendix

I have a problem with cross-referencing a table in my appendix. Somehow, the table is appearing as "Table I" when it is created, but when I try to cross-reference it later in the appendix, it is being referenced as "Table A" (see code and resulting pdf below). Has anyone else experienced this problem before? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[prx,aps,epsfig,twocolumn]{revtex4} 
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, linktocpage]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % needed for figures
\usepackage{dcolumn}   % needed for some tables

\begin{document}

\begin{appendix}

\section{Section Title}

\begin{table}[tbp!]
\label{tab:example}
\caption{caption here}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
 \textbf{column 1} &  \textbf{column 2} & \textbf{column 3} \\ \hline
a & b & c \\ \hline
d & e & f \\ \hline
g & h & i \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Let's try to reference Table \ref{tab:example}. Why does it appear as "Table A" instead of "Table I"?????

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled pdf:]

Comment: Put the `\label` *after* the `\caption`.

Comment: Ah that worked wonderfully, thank you!!!